# best data structure for country,state,city,zip-code hierarchy

Tags: java, caching, data-structures

I am creating an application where I have to store all the departmental stores and want to cache it.

the hierarchy would be like:-

Country -> State -> City -> Area-> Stores

which data structure should I use So my application will work like if

1. I query for country and state, it should give me all the store
2. I query for country and state and city, it should give me all the stores in that area.

I just thought of Tree, but not able to convert this scenario into this data structure.

Comment: The best tool for this schema is probably some sort of database.  Any reason why you aren't using one?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen all the data  stores in one table and I have to query once on that table, and to cache it and want to query on that

Comment: I think that you might get further adding the right indices and tuning that table rather than trying to handle this purely in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just build the hierarchy, with each level containing a Map of the next level down:

```
class Store {
   string name;
   // other stuff
}

class Area {
    string name;
    Map<string, Store> stores;
    // other stuff;
}

class City {
    string name;
    Map<string, Area> areas;
    // other stuff
}

class State {
    string name;
    Map<string, City> cities;
    // other stuff
}

class Country {
    string name;
    Map<string, State> states;
    // other stuff
}
```

And you have a `Map` of countries at class scope:

```
Map<string, Country> countries;
```

If you want all the stores in a particular Country, State, and City, you first have to get a reference to the city:

```
Country country = countries[countryName];
State state = country.states[stateName];
City city = state.cities[cityName];
```

Now, for each area in the city, you visit each of the stores:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Area> pair : city.areas.entrySet())
{
    Area area = entry.getValue();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Store> storePair : areas.stores.entrySet())
    {
        // Here, pair.getKey() is the store name
        // and pair.getValue() is the Store object
    }
}
```

This is really just a hierarchical tree implemented with nested dictionaries. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1):

You state that you want to **cache** the information. If that is true, and you do not want to alter it, but **only** cache it, I would recommend to forego the tree idea and simply build two maps based on the key combinations you really need, i.e.:

- one cache mapping a type 1 key (consisting of country and state) to a list of stores
- one cache mapping a type 2 key (consisting of country, state and city) to a list of stores in the area

That is the point of a cache, really: You want to put all the logic (which store belongs to which combination of key values) into the construction of the cache (initial or on first request) and not start any kind of iteration every time you do a lookup.